# How to use ngx-intl-tel-input library in Angular 14

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular14, libphonenumber

I want to import library ngx-intl-tel-input to validate phone number with the country code in reactiveForm module and when change country code the phone number should be blank please guide me or share me with the patch value on edit time  the demo link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-ng-12

I want to use ngx-intl-tel-input for phone number vaildate with the country code and set phone number on edit patch